# Convert UTC or BST to local users time zone in dojo

Tags: javascript, node.js, dojo, datetime-format

I am getting my date field as `UTC` or  `BST` time that I need to convert to my local time zone .

This is my function :

```
exports.date = function formatDate(vpDate) {
    return vpDate ? dateUtils.toString(vpDate) : " ";
};
```

This is what I am returning as of now Here is my sample `vpDate ="04-Oct-2019 13:48";`

How can I convert to local time zone in the same format .
I tried using `toLocaleString`  and few more things but I am not able to get it correctly .

any help would be appreciated .

This is how i use dojo

```
columnConfiguration: {
            "auditDate": {
                formatter: formatters.date,
                sortable: true
            },
            "actionedBy": {
                sortable: true
            },
            "action": {
                formatter: _actionFormatter,
                sortable: true
            }
        }
    });
```

then from here i am calling my above function .

**Now this coming correct but still but format is wrong**

This is the output `Fri Oct 04 2019 19:24:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

which is wrong

```
exports.date = function formatDate(vpDateObj) {
        var vpDate = locale.parse(dateUtils.toString(vpDateObj), {datePattern: "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm", selector: "date"});
        alert (vpDate);
        return vpDate ? vpDate.toString(vpDate) : " ";
    };
```

Comment: "in the same format" as what? Presuming `vpDate` here is a standard JavaScript `Date` object, it has no intrinsic format that relates to how the date was originally acquired.

Comment: @kshetline added sample date format ..Thnaks

Answer (score 1):

You can use dojo local:[format](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html) function to format a date object into your corresponding format, by using locale.format and passing date and object containing pattern you want to convert to using `datePattern:"yourpattern"`

See below snippet how it works :

```js
require(["dojo/date/locale"
], function(locale) {
  var vpDate  = new Date();
  
  var format1 = locale.format( vpDate , {selector:"date", datePattern:"ddMMyy" } );
  
  var format2 = locale.format( vpDate , {selector:"date", datePattern:"MM-dd-yyyy" } );
  
    var format3 = locale.format( vpDate , {selector:"date", datePattern:"MM / dd / yyyy ss:mm:SSS" } );
    
    
  console.log("ddMMyy -----> ", format1);
  console.log("MM-dd-yyyy -> ",format2);
  console.log("MM /dd/yyyy ss:mm:SSS -> ",format3);
  
});
```

```html
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script>
  dojoConfig = {
    parseOnLoad: true,
    async: true
  };
</script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks good to me but as  i am very new to dojo ...Is there any way i can accomodate into my function

Comment: I am getting all as null ..Dont know how to call this function

Comment: could you post how you use dojo ? and wish version ?  post just heading how you import and your function

Comment: Just now i posted piece of code from where i am calling date  function  in formatter

Comment: @this just a config for a table I guess ! , wich version are you using ?

Comment: 1.15 i feel ..I can not tell that exactly with the jar i can say

Comment: I cant figure out how it work , could you make a bin here , where you paste the whole example : https://pastebin.com/index.php?e=2

Comment: Its almost working just date fomrat is coming wrong i am getting in `Fri Oct 04 2019 19:24:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` format ..I have updated my question also ..

Comment: Use. format instead of parse. So pass the date directly to format without dateutilsb.

Comment: Yes i tried that but i anot getting correct time ..I still get UTC time only ..

Comment: `var vpDate  = dateUtils.toString(vpDateObj);
  var date = new Date(vpDate)
  var format2 = locale.format( date , {selector:"date", datePattern:"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm" } );
  alert(format2);`

Comment: that's weird , should alert time in pattern format , no way !

Comment: Yes ..When i parse then i get in local time but format is different

Comment: check before and after using format , my be the function  is not called$

Comment: yes, Hope you'll find fix , cause I can't figure out where is the problem :)

Comment: Yes ..This is my date before calling the format method `Fri Oct 04 2019 13:48:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`  and after format i am getting this `04-Oct-2019 13:48`

Answer (score 0):

Dojo has date formatting support, described here: https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/format.html

A string in this format: `04-Oct-2019 13:48`

Corresponds to this format specification: `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm`

Comment: I did not get the solution ..Do i have to write seperate function ? I am very new to dojo so might asking very basic question

Comment: I don't know Dojo at all, I just looked it up now. :) But it looks like it's just a matter of using an existing Dojo formatting method, which takes your date and a object containing options (one of which can be the date format).

Answer (score 0):

You can use formatDate(); function.
formatDate() shows the correct date and time according to the time zone

```
  function formatDate(date) {
      return date.getFullYear() + '/' + 
      (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + 
      date.getDate() + ' ' + 
      date.getHours() + ':' + 
      date.getMinutes();
     }


     const seoul = new Date(1489199400000);

     formatDate(seoul);  // 2017/3/11 11:30
```